# Display Single Result from Returned List

Tags: php, api, twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to work out how I can display the first returned value (phone number) only. At the moment this code returns ALL available numbers but I only want to display one to the customer.

Here's the code. I hope someone can help. I'm pretty new to this you see, I've tried a few bits but they haven't worked.

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "AC1f3ccf29618exxxxx"; 
$token = "{{Auth_Token}}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('GB', 'Local', array(
        "Contains" => "44161"
    ));

foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) { 
echo $number->phone_number;
}

?>
```

Currently I get a list as follows:

```
+441618503707+441618503748+441618502214+441618502601+441618502327+441618503631+441618503785+441618503437+441618503432+441618503758+441618503593+441618503404+441618503794+441618502289+441618503684+441618503519+441618503629+441618503810+441618503704+441618503742+441618503557+441618503302+441618503604+441618503539+441618503044+441618503298+441618503799+441618503753+441618503447+441618503801
```

I would just like to display the first value IE `+441618503707`

Help appreciated, I may not respond right away as this is one of many projects on at the moment. Rest assured though my other projects are on Infusionsoft, I don't dabble in API/PHP too often!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you can use this

```
echo $numbers->available_phone_numbers[0]->phone_number;
```

it will contains first in the array .

**Update**

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "AC1f3ccf29618exxxxx"; 
$token = "{{Auth_Token}}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('GB', 'Local', array(
        "Contains" => "44161"
    ));

echo $numbers->available_phone_numbers[0]->phone_number;

?>
```

Comment: Hi @ShowStopper, I tried that and it does return one phone number just multiple times. Any ideas on how to get that displaying only the once?

Comment: don't use it in foreach dude. use it outside foreach.

Comment: Hi @ShowStopper, thanks for your help on this, that works perfectly! Onto step two, purchasing the number, gawd help the poor guy who's money I'm spending haha!